# Inductive proof that $\dot{M}_{n+1}=-M_{n+1}+W^{(n+2)}(0)+vM_{n+2}$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, differential-calculus

The motivation for the following is to convert the integro-differential equation

\begin{equation}
    \kappa\ddot x+\dot x=-kx+\beta\int_{-\infty}^t W'(x(t)-x(s))e^{s-t}ds,
\end{equation}

into a system of nonlinear ODEs

\begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \dot{x}&=v,\\
            \dot{v}&=\frac{1}{\kappa}(\beta M_0-v-kx),\\
            \dot{M}_n&=-M_n+W^{(n+1)}(0)+vM_{n+1}.
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}

Let

$$M_n=\int_{-\infty}^t W^{(n+1)}(x(t)-x(s))e^{s-t}ds,$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $W^{(n+1)}(z)$ is the $n+1$-th derivative of $W$ with respect to $z$. I can't see how the last line of the proof below is equivalent to $-M_{n+1}+W^{(n+2)}(0)+vM_{n+2}$? Perhaps I made the wrong substitution on line 3. Any help would be much appreciated.

Applying the Leibniz integral rule, observe that for $n=0$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \dot{M_0}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^t W^{(1)}(x(t)-x(s))e^{s-t}ds\\
    &=W^{(1)}(0)+\int_{-\infty}^t e^{s-t}\left(\dot{x}W^{(2)}(x(t)-x(s))-W^{(1)}(x(t)-x(s))\right)ds,\\
    &=-M_0+W^{(1)}(0)+\dot{x}M_1.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
The inductive step is then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \dot{M}_{n+1}
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\dot{M}_n+M_n-W^{(n+1)}(0)}{v}\right),\\
    &=\frac{v\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dot{M}_n+M_n-W^{(n+1)}(0)\right)-\dot{v}(\dot{M}_n+M_n-W^{(n+1)}(0))}{v^2},\\
    &=\frac{v\ddot{M}_n+v\dot{M}_n-\dot{v}\dot{M}_n-\dot{v}M_n-vW^{(n+2)}(0)+\dot{v}W^{(n+1)}(0)}{v^2},\\
    &=\frac{\ddot{M}_n+\dot{M}_n-\dot{v}M_{n+1}-W^{(n+2)}(0)}{v}.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you did for $n=0$, for any $n\ge0$ write
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \dot{M_n}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^t W^{(n+1)}(x(t)-x(s))e^{s-t}ds\\
    &=W^{(1)}(0)+\int_{-\infty}^t e^{s-t}\left(\dot{x}(t)W^{(n+2)}(x(t)-x(s))-W^{(n+1)}(x(t)-x(s))\right)ds \\
    &=-M_n+W^{(n+1)}(0)+\dot{x}M_{n+1},
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
to get the desired result.

Induction is not needed here. Also, your multiline differentiation display is incorrect. In particular, the derivative of the constant $W^{(n+1)}(0)$ is $0$, not $W^{(n+2)}(0)$.